# Fit image to table cell [Pure HTML]

Tags: html

How do i fit image to table `td` cell? [Pure HTML]

I have tried below code to fit an image in table `td` cell.

HTML code is here :

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#aaa" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td><img width="100%" height="100%" src="http://dummyimage.com/68x68/000/fff" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see in following screenshot and in [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk2Rh/), that image doesn't fit to `td` cell.

Shot :

[image]

What am i doing wrong ?

Any suggestion would be awesome.

Comment: `img { display:block; }`

Comment: @MattWhipple . I said pure HTML...

Comment: pure HTML shouldn't be doing styling.  The moment it does it wouldn't be considered pure outside of the '90's.

Comment: @HamedKamrava You ask "what am I doing wrong?" Well, I'm afraId what you're doing wrong is trying to find a pure HTML solution. How come you're unable to use styles?

Comment: @MrLister I can use styles but i don't want use it.

Comment: I've uploaded the code to my own server, and it fits? Something wrong with JSfiddle? http://digletts.com/testing/test.html

Comment: Title should be 'Fitting TABLE around IMG', it looks like...

Comment: Lol, Is there any reason you don't want to use css?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Inline content leaves space at the bottom for characters that descend (j, y, q):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

There are a couple fixes:

Use `display: block;`

```
<img style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://dummyimage.com/68x68/000/fff" />
```

or use `vertical-align: bottom;`

```
<img style="vertical-align: bottom;" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://dummyimage.com/68x68/000/fff" />
```

Answer (score 6):

It's all about `display: block` :)

**Updated**:

Ok so you have the table, tr and td tags:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- your image goes here -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Lets say your `table` or `td` (whatever define your width) has property `width: 360px;`. Now, when you try to replace the html comment with the actual image and set that image property for example `width: 100%;` which should fully fill out the **`td`** cell you will face the problem.

The **problem** is that your table cell (`td`) isn't properly filled with the image. You'll notice the space at the bottom of the cell which your image doesn't cover (it's like 5px of padding).

**How to solve this in a simpliest way?**

You are working with the tables, right? You just need to add the *display* property to your image so that it has the following:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so if you have a table and image stored in the td cell - your td has some width, right? In order image to fit that width you have to assign the **display: block;** property to your image.

Comment: Actually, it is more in the spirit of StackOverflow is you edit your answer, instead of giving precision in a comment to the answer. :-)

Comment: I did. I hope you find that useful.

Comment: Indeed, that is a lot better! The OP will probably accept your answer, now.

Answer (score 0):

Use your developer's tool of choice and check if the `tr`, `td` or `img` has any padding or margins.

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain more? i'm confused

Comment: Using for example Chrome's Developer Tools you can right click on an element and check if there is any margins och paddings on the elements enclosing the image.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with pure HTML solution ,you can delete the border in the table if you want...or you can add align="center" attribute to your img tag like this:

```
<img align="center" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://dummyimage.com/68x68/000/fff" />
```

see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lk2Rh/27/

but still it better to handling this with CSS, i suggest you that.

- I hope this help.