# Html2pdf Image in cell overlaps other cells

Tags: html, css, html2pdf

I'm using [Html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf) and facing strange issue:

[image: overlapping image]

As you see my image is inside table and is overlapping `tr` below it

Html structure:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="page-title">
                Running style - head and arms isolated           
            </td>
            <td>
                EARLY: Physical - Fast
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="images single">
            <td colspan="2">
                <img src="http://example.com" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="block-header">
                Outcomes                    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Know how to keep head still and employ efficient, correct arm drive
            </td>
        </tr>
        /* ... */
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    td {
        width: 50%;
    }

    tr img {
        width: 70%;
    }
</style>
```

Printing as HTML produces correct result.

Any idea what can be issue?

Comment: img { display:block; } Also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393090/fit-image-to-table-cell-pure-html

Comment: @KaasiasKomplex This does nothing.

Comment: You should provide complete styles for of this document. Its enough code. This code is working well in my browser.

Comment: @AnkitGupta Did you test it using Html2Pdf or just browser rendered table?

Comment: I have tested it with all conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some facts that leads to error:

1. `td` has only `50%` width
2. In browser view `colspan="2"` will lead to `100%` width of cell.

Now to fix that issue all I had to do is to set `tr.single td {width: 100%}`.
Adding that line fixed image overlap issue in HTML2PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Height of the image explicitly:

```
...
        <td colspan="2">
            <img style="height:350px" src="http://example.com" alt="">
        </td>
...
```

Comment: I can't set explicit height. Images may vary in dimensions. So image 1000x350 will ruin layout

Comment: I see, could you provide a direct link for the image causing this problem?

Comment: Also, you don't have to set the width, just the height should be enough and this will let the width be in same ratio.

Comment: @Justinas If you set an explicit height, does it work? Do you have limit of how big the image could be?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure but if specifying the image height will you maybe you can get the img height with js   img.naturalheight();

```
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
var newImg = new Image();

newImg.onload = function() {
  var height = newImg.height;
  alert ('The image size is '+height);}


newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a blank div with a specific height on a new row following the image. so that there is enough space between the bottom of the image and the top of where the text begins.

```
<div style="height:200px;Width:100px;">&nbsp</div>
```

so it would look something like this

```
    <tr class="images single">
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="http://example.com" alt="">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="height:200px;Width:100px;">&nbsp</div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="block-header">
            Outcomes                    
        </td>
    </tr>
```

you might have to do trial an error with the div's style's height. the width isn't that important.

Also check to see if you set the height or width or position (ie: Position:Absolute;) in the "images single" class style that maybe what's causing the overlay.

If that doesn't work then maybe try putting the Div in the same cell as the text but just before the text begins.

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="block-header">

              <div style="height:200px;Width:100px;">&nbsp</div>

            Outcomes                    
        </td>
    </tr>
```