# Fit image to table cell using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, cell

I have been experiencing this issue when doing my lab. So what I'm doing is there is a table and when I click a button it will append an image to some specific cells in the table. However, the table becomes distorted every time the images appear (You can see as in the attached image below). The display:block doesn't work. I have tried to add display:block to img tag in css as default and it also didn't work.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGdlk.jpg)

This is my code for adding the image:

```
$("table").find("tr").eq(1).find("td").eq(1).append("<img src='image.png' style='display:block;' width='100%' height='auto'/>");
```

This is my css for the table (box is the id of the table):

```
#box {
        height: 400px; 
        width: 400px;
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: -200px;
        margin-top: -200px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: can you add some html and put all code in snippet

Comment: Your code will work for only one row, not for others.

Comment: Try `overflow:hidden` in the `CSS`. Also it is `style='display:block;width:100%;height:auto'/>` Why do you want it `block`?

Comment: `.eq(1)` it's mean the first row/cell allways

Comment: This is just to illustrate what I'm doing

Comment: Well, I just follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393090/fit-image-to-table-cell-pure-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give fixed width and height to the table cells so that it won't be distorted on time of adding images.

```js
function addImage() {
  $("table").find("tr").eq(1).find("td").eq(1).append("<img src='https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-5.jpg' style='display:block;' width='100%' height='auto'/>");
}
```

```css
table img {
  width: 200px;
}
table td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
<button onClick='addImage()'>Click</button>
```

Try this and let me know if this was what your requirement was.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the table cells dimension constant, then you either have to,

- set the constant width and height to the all td (or)
- Add new div container for image to each td with width and height set

> Reason for the table getting distorted is, as there is no set dimension set to the table cells, the row and column to which image is attached is retaining the height and width and the other rows and columns having no data became tiny

Comment: Thanks. I get it.