# unwanted borders when I use <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, css, doctype

[image]If I use  !DOCTYPE html , unwanted borders appear at the lower corners of the header. I used images in order to get these corners.  Same issue  for Internet explorer and Chrome. How can I remove these borders ? If I use  !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN   there is not any problem.

The codes are:

```css
  body {
             font-family : arial, sans-serif;
             background-color: #FFFFF0;
              margin:0;
             }

             div.header {
              width: 100%;
              text-align: center;
              background-color: #0000CC;
              float: left;    
              padding:0.001em;
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <HTML>
             <HEAD>
              <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
                   </HEAD>
                  <BODY>
                <DIV class="header">

                  <IMG SRC="http://www.usefulchess.com/kq.gif" BORDER="0" WIDTH="80" HEIGHT="63" 
                   ALT="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<IMG SRC="http://www.usefulchess.com/useful.gif" 
                   BORDER="0" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="49" ALT="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<IMG 
                    SRC="http://www.usefulchess.com/chess.gif" BORDER="0" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="60" ALT="">
                   <IMG SRC="http://www.usefulchess.com/sembol.gif" BORDER="0" WIDTH="255" HEIGHT="84" 
                    ALT="" class="sembol">
    
                          </DIV>
    


                       <DIV class="menudesktop"><!-- menu desktop -->
                        <!-- BUTTON-->

                     <TABLE bgcolor="#0000CC" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0">
                      <TR><TD>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>
                        </TABLE>
                      <TABLE bgcolor="#0000CC" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">



                        <TR>
                       <TD  WIDTH="3%" HEIGHT="25"><IMG SRC="http://www.usefulchess.com/left2.gif" 
                        BORDER="0" WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="25" ALT="">
                        </TD>

                        <TD align="center" WIDTH="95%" HEIGHT="25">
                   <A HREF="../index.html" class=button>Home</A>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <a href="../play/playchess.html" class="button">Play Chess</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <a href="../rules/chess-rules.html" class="button">Chess Rules</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <a href="../tactics/chess-tactics.html" class="button">Chess Tactics</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <a href="../problems/chessproblem2_1.html" class="button">Problems </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <a href="../studies/chess_study1.html" class="button">Studies </a>

                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <A HREF="../store/chess_books.html" class="button">Books</A>

                          </TD>

                    <TD WIDTH="2%" HEIGHT="25"><IMG SRC="http://www.usefulchess.com/right2.gif" 
                     BORDER="0" WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="25" ALT="">
                        </TD>

                         
                         </TR>
                           </TABLE>

                             </DIV><!-- menu desktop end-->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Can You please add a Screen Shot so we can understand it better : )

Comment: Pretty sure the bits you are referring to are caused by the `bgcolor` attribute on the `<table>` element that includes them.  Pretty sure this is obsolete in HTML5 (which is effectively the HTML standard you are declaring with the `<!DOCTYPE html>` bit

Comment: 1) Don't use tables for layouts 2) Don't use `&nbsp;` for spacing 3) Don't use images for text 4) If you _do_ use images for text, make sure they have the `alt` attribute set to what the text says 5) Don't put dark blue text on top of a dark blue background 6) `<!-- -->`-style comments are invalid in CSS - you need to use `/* */` style instead 7) Don't mix uppercase and lowercase tag names 8) Fix the indentation so that tags line up with their place in the DOM tree 9) Style things with CSS rather than obsolete attributes like `bgcolor` 10) You're missing a closing `</body>` tag

Comment: As for what you should use for layout, check out [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it  by using:  display: block;  Example: <img style="display:block;" ....  [Details on stackoverflow.com : Fit image to table cell [Pure HTML]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393090/fit-image-to-table-cell-pure-html)
Using bgcolor with   !DOCTYPE html   created also this unwanted borders.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.